# How to list GitLab subgroups using JGit?

Tags: git, svn, gitlab, jgit

I am investigating the possibility of migrating SVN projects to Git. We have an eclipse RCP application which stores 'projects' in an SVN repository. We have 2 repositories: one for Prod and one for Test. The 'projects' can be checked out, committed and tagged as the user requires. They are all independent of each other.

We now use Gitlab where all of our development work and we want to migrate the application to use Git instead of SVN.

While reviewing the SVN use-cases, I ran into a problem that I haven't been able to resolve.

One feature of the application is that the user can browse the repository, view the available projects and check-out one or more projects into the local workspace.

Gitlab provides `subgroups` but - as far as I know - these are not the same as Git `submodules`. I have tried to access a Gitlab `subgroup` using JGit but, as it is not a repository, it fails.

My question is:

Is there a way to organise projects in Git in such a way that I can list all projects in a group using JGit?